# Close icon on ajax registeration form closing the form, but not clearing all data fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I tried to create a close icon on right top of form. It closes the form, but when I reopen page without reload, all data fields come up with data.

How can I clear all fields automatically when I close the form?

Html code (with JavaScript inline, at the bottom):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="myBtn"><a href="#">Register With Us</a></li>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <form>

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #fff;">
                    <span class="close"><img src="images/index/close.png" width="40px;" height="40px;" ></span>

                    <h1 style="padding-top: 0px;"> WELCOME TO LOGIN PAGE</h1>

                    <div class="controls">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_name">First Name *</label>
                                    <input id="form_name" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your first name *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_lastname">Last Name *</label>
                                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your last name *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_dob">Date of Birth *</label><br>
                                    <input id="form_dob" type="date" name="dob" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Date of Birth *" required="required" data-error="Date of Birth is required.">

                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_gender" style="padding-right: 15px;">Gender *</label>
                                    <label class="gender"><input type="radio" required  autocomplete="off" name='gender' value='Male'><img src="images/index/male.png" width="40px" height="35px" > Male</label><label class="gender"><input type="radio" autocomplete="off" required name='gender' value='Female'><img src="images/index/female.png" width="40px" height="35px">Female</label>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_nationality"> Nationality *</label><br>
                                    <select required name="Nationalty" class="form-control" style=" text-align: center;" autocomplete="off">
    <option value=''  ><strong >Select Your Nationality</strong></option>

      <option value="BGD">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="IND">India</option>
      <option value="NEP">Nepal</option>
      <option value="PAK">Pakistan</option>

      <option value="SL">Sri Lanka</option>
                        </select>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_photo" style="padding-right: 20px;">Photo *</label>
                                    <input type="file" class=" myButton " autocomplete="off" />
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required." autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_phone">Phone No *</label>
                                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone *" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_passport_no">Passport No *</label>
                                    <input id="form_passport_no" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Passport Number *" required="required" data-error="Valid Passport is required." autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_passport_expiry">Passport Expiry Date*</label>
                                    <input id="form_passport_expiry" type="date" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Passport Expiry Date" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_visa_issue">Visa Issue Date *</label>
                                    <input id="form_visa_issue" type="date" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Visa Issue Date *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required." autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_visa_expiry">Visa Expiry Date  *</label>
                                    <input id="form_visa_expiry" type="date" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Visa Expiry Date" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_message">Company Details *</label>
                                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please provide company Details *" rows="4" required data-error="Please,leave us a message." autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input id="reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-ghost " value="Reset" style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: 35%;">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-ghost " value="Register" style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: 50px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

        </form>
        <script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
            btn.onclick = function() {


                modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            }

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() {

                modal.style.display = "none";

            };

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Fixed capitalization and punctuation for improved readability. Stated problem as a question.

Comment: well, yeah, your code just shows and hides it...

Answer (score 0):

Reset your form..on closing window and clicking close button.
Like this...

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();//myForm is your form id
```

OR using jquery reset your form. `$("#myForm")[0].reset();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {

    modal.style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

};






// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call jquery trigger function to reset button when you close the form and when open the form it will reset your form and all fields will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not using bootstrap functions.

To close modal, you didn't need new javascript! Bootstrap.js do it itself. Add data-dismiss="modal" to your button. Have a look on this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

With bootstrap, you can overload the hidden event by a function.

```js
/**
 * When moddal is closing...
 */
$('myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // Reset form !
    $("#myForm")[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have any id with the form and assuming you only have one form on the page following code should work. Add a statement right before you show the form.

```
modal.style.display = "block";
document.forms[0].reset()
```